# HANDLER / HandlerSocket and indexes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, handlersocket

What is the difference between Handler and HandlerSocket? Is the second one something like an improvement of the first one and therefore is preferable? I didn't find any explanation of the differences between them or any comparisons.

Can Handler and/or HandlerSocket retrieve from indexes, or does it work with tables only?

Comment: 1) I used google, took me around 10 seconds to get [this link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/handlersocket-external-resources/) which has a link that compares `HANDLER` and `HandlerSocket` - [here's that link as well](http://varokism.blogspot.com/2010/12/using-mysql-as-nosql-story-for_27.html).

2) Why is that important? If you're asking the question under number #2, that means you definitely don't need to use HandlerSocket or Handler. Why would you retrieve anything from indexes? You already have that in the table, what you need to do is tell the engine to use the index to find the row

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Comment: As for the second question: I was wondering whether HANDLER can use indexes or it goes straight to tables every time.

Comment: @Mjh sorry forgot to mention you in the comment